# Lineup labels on bootstrap form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap form and I would like to lineup the country label inline with the country select element, the code currently renders as follows:

[image: layout]

My source is below:

```
<fieldset>
    <label class="control-label" for="firstName">Billing Contact</label>
    <div class="controls controls-row">
        <input id="firstName" class="span3" type="text" data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { placeholder: 'First Name' }" />
        <input id="lastName" class="span3" type="text" data-bind="value: lastName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { placeholder: 'Last Name' }" />
    </div>
    <div class="controls controls-row">
        <input id="address1" class="span6" type="text" data-bind="value: address1, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { placeholder: 'Street Address' }" />
    </div>
    <div class="controls controls-row">
        <input id="address2" class="span6" type="text" data-bind="value: address2, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { placeholder: 'Apt, Suite, Building (optional)' }" />
    </div>
    <div class="controls controls-row">
        <input id="city" class="span4" type="text" data-bind="value: city, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { placeholder: 'City' }" />
        <input id="PostalCode" class="span2" type="text" data-bind="value: postalCode, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { placeholder: 'Postal Code' }" />
    </div>
    <div class="controls controls-row">
        <label class="control-label">Country</label>
        <select id="country" class="span4" data-bind="options: countriesList, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'code', value: selectedCountry, attr: { placeholder: 'Country' }" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I have two questions please:

1. How can I render the country label inline
2. How can i render inline, but make the country select take up the remaining width (so the right of the box lines up with the other span6 elements)

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/rqjB2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the last `controls-row`:

```html
<div class="controls controls-row">
  <label class="control-label">Country</label>
  <select id="country" class="span4" />
</div>
```

To the above, changing `controls controls-row` to `control-group form-inline` and add `<div class="controls"></div>` inside:

```html
<div class="control-group form-inline">
  <div class="controls">
    <label class="control-label">Country</label>
    <select id="country" class="span4" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `form-horizontal` class on your form element
2. You can use the `input-block-level` class to make the element fill the width of its parent container. *** Note, if you use `form-horizontal`, you could just use span6 because `form-horizontal` will make all of your form elements align vertically.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rqjB2/1/) is an example. I had to move the "Country" label outside of the "Controls" container div for this to work properly.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. I dont want all the labels to be form-horizontal, the Billing Contact info should be where it is as per my original pic. Form-horizontal shifts everything over and pushes labels inline, where as only the Country 'label' should be on the same line as the country select. If the html element type needs to change from label that is ok, but I have also tried <p>Country</p> and that didn't work either.